# Converting TELNET script to SSH

Tags: ssh, telnet, cisco

I need to change the TELNET method to SSH(using 1024 bits) and i find it hard to follow..
The main issue is to use the the SSH lib with paramiko but without success.
There is the relevant code:

```
import subprocess
import getpass
import telnetlib
import time
import ast
import os


def GetFile(message, mandatory):
    CMDFILE = ''
    while not CMDFILE:
        CMDFILE = raw_input(message + ' (default extention .txt): ')
        if (not CMDFILE and mandatory): print 'This file is mandatory!\n'
        else:
            if '.' not in CMDFILE: CMDFILE = CMDFILE + '.txt'
            if CMDFILE not in os.listdir('.'):
                print '{} not found!\n'.format(CMDFILE)
                CMDFILE = ""
    return CMDFILE

def LoginDevice(tn, login, password, enable):
    tn.expect(['login:','Username:','username:'], 10)
    tn.write(user + "\n")
    tn.expect(['Password:','password:','Pass:'], 10)
    tn.write(password + "\n")
    CORRECTLOGIN = tn.expect(['#','/cli>','>','login:','Username:','username:'], 10)
    CORRECTENABLE = [2,]
    if CORRECTLOGIN[0] == 2:
        print 'Need enable'
        tn.write('enable\n')
        tn.write(enable + '\n')
        CORRECTENABLE = tn.expect(['#','>'], 10)
        if CORRECTENABLE[0] == 1:
            print 'Incorrent enable password, aborting {}'.format(DEVICE.rstrip())
            return False, '>' 
    if ( CORRECTLOGIN[0] == 0 or CORRECTENABLE[0] == 0):
        tn.write("\n")
        full_device_prompt = tn.read_until("#", 10)
        return True, full_device_prompt.strip(), '#'
    elif CORRECTLOGIN[0] == 1:
        return True, '/cli>', '/cli>'
    else:
        return False, ''
    
    
user = ""
password = ""
enablepass = ""
prompt = ""
dead_devices = 0
conn_errors_devices = 0
enable_errors_devices = 0
conn_devices = 0

while not user:
    user = raw_input("Enter user ID: ")
    if not user: print 'User name is mandatory!\n'

while not password:
    password = getpass.getpass()
    if not password: print 'Password is mandatory!\n'


enablepass = getpass.getpass('Enable password (blank if no need): ')

CMDFILE = GetFile("Enter commands file name", True)

DEVFILE = GetFile("Enter devices list file name", True)

OUTFILE = raw_input("Enter output file name <default output.txt>: ")
if not OUTFILE: OUTFILE = 'output.txt'

SCROUTPUT = raw_input('Display outout on screen y/n? <n>: ')
if SCROUTPUT == "y":
    SCROUTPUT = True
else:
    SCROUTPUT = False

DEVICESFILE = open(DEVFILE)

CMD = [line for line in open(CMDFILE)]
if CMD[0].split(',')[0] == 'separator':
    separator = CMD[0].split(',')[1].strip()
    CMD.pop(0)
else:
    separator = ','

OUT = open(OUTFILE,"wb")

logfile = open('log.txt','a')
start_time = time.time()

print '\n' * 2
print 'Starting new run: {}'.format(time.asctime( time.localtime(start_time) ))
print '*' * 50 + '\n' * 2
logfile.write('Starting new run: {}\n'.format(time.asctime( time.localtime(start_time) )))
logfile.write('*' * 50 + '\n')


for DEVICE in DEVICESFILE:
    if DEVICE[0] =='#':
        print
        print "Skipping %s \n" % DEVICE.rstrip()
        logfile.write("Skipping %s \n" % DEVICE.rstrip())
    else:
        p = subprocess.Popen("ping -c 1 " + DEVICE.strip(), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        p.wait()
        if not p.returncode:
            ping_str = p.stdout.read()
            print 'Checking reachability for {}'.format(DEVICE.rstrip())
            print '--------------------------------------------------'
            print 'Ping time is: {}'.format(ping_str.split('\n')[1].split()[6])
            try:
                tn = telnetlib.Telnet(DEVICE.rstrip(), 23, 30)
                loging_in = LoginDevice(tn, user, password, enablepass)
                if loging_in[0]:
                    show_prompt = loging_in[1]
                    command_prompt = loging_in[2]
                    conn_devices += 1
                    tn.write("\n")
                    DEVICE_NAME = tn.read_until(show_prompt, 10)
                    OUT.write ("Output from: {} ({})\n".format(DEVICE_NAME.strip(), DEVICE.rstrip()))
                    OUT.write ("------------------------------------------------------\n")
                    print '\nConnected to {} {}'.format(DEVICE_NAME.strip(), DEVICE.rstrip())
                    for LINE in CMD:
                        COMMAND = LINE.split(separator)
                        if COMMAND[0] == "o":
                            tn.write(COMMAND[1].strip() + '\n')
                            OUTPUT = tn.read_until(show_prompt, 240)
                            if SCROUTPUT: print OUTPUT[:OUTPUT.find(DEVICE_NAME.strip())]
                            OUT.write (OUTPUT[:OUTPUT.find(DEVICE_NAME.strip())] + '\n')
                        elif COMMAND[0] == "xo":
                            if COMMAND[1] == DEVICE.rstrip():
                                tn.write(COMMAND[2].strip() + '\n')
                                OUTPUT = tn.read_until(show_prompt, 120)
                                if SCROUTPUT: print OUTPUT[:OUTPUT.find(DEVICE_NAME.strip())]
                                OUT.write (OUTPUT[:OUTPUT.find(DEVICE_NAME.strip())] + '\n')
                        if COMMAND[0] == "ifo":
                            tn.write(COMMAND[1].strip() + '\n')
                            OUTPUT = tn.read_until(show_prompt, 120)
                            if COMMAND[2] in OUTPUT:
                                tn.write(COMMAND[3].strip() + '\n')
                                OUTPUT = tn.read_until(show_prompt, 120)
                            else:
                                tn.write(COMMAND[4].strip() + '\n')
                                OUTPUT = tn.read_until(show_prompt, 120)
                            if SCROUTPUT: print OUTPUT[:OUTPUT.find(DEVICE_NAME.strip())]
                            OUT.write (OUTPUT[:OUTPUT.find(DEVICE_NAME.strip())] + '\n')
                        elif COMMAND[0] == "c":
                            tn.write(COMMAND[1].strip() + '\n')
                            tn.read_until(command_prompt, 20)
                        elif COMMAND[0] == "xc":
                            if COMMAND[1] == DEVICE.rstrip():
                                tn.write(COMMAND[2].strip() + '\n')
                                tn.read_until(command_prompt, 20)
                        elif COMMAND[0] == "s":
                            time.sleep(ast.literal_eval(COMMAND[1]))
                    OUT.write ("\n" * 2)
                else:
                    print 'Incorrent password, aborting {}'.format(DEVICE.rstrip())
                    logfile.write('Incorrent password, aborting {}'.format(DEVICE.rstrip()))
                    enable_errors_devices += 1
                tn.close()
                
            except IOError, msg:
                print str(msg[1])
                logfile.write('{}: {}\n'.format(DEVICE.rstrip(),str(msg[1])))
                conn_errors_devices += 1
                
        else:
            print '\n\n{} is unreachable'.format(DEVICE.strip())
            print "-------------------"
            logfile.write('{} is unreachable\n'.format(DEVICE.rstrip()))
            dead_devices += 1
        print '\n' * 2
        if OUTFILE:
            OUT.write ("\n")
#        CMD.seek(0)

print '\n' + '*' * 15
print '* Run summary *'
print '*' * 15
print 'ExCMD version: 2.2'
print 'Command file: {}'.format(CMDFILE)
print 'Devices file: {}'.format(DEVFILE)
print 'Total run time: {:.2f}sec'.format(time.time() - start_time)
print 'Total responding devices: {}'.format(conn_devices)
print "Total unreachable devices: {}".format(dead_devices)
print 'Total devices that had connection errors: {}'.format(conn_errors_devices)
print 'Total devices that had enable password errors: {}'.format(enable_errors_devices)

logfile.write('\n' + '*' * 15 + '\n')
logfile.write('* Run summary *\n')
logfile.write('*' * 15 + '\n')
logfile.write('ExCMD version: 2.2\n')
logfile.write('Command file: {}\n'.format(CMDFILE))
logfile.write('Devices file: {}\n'.format(DEVFILE))
logfile.write('Total run time: {:.2f}sec\n'.format(time.time() - start_time))
logfile.write('Total responding devices: {}\n'.format(conn_devices))
logfile.write("Total unreachable devices: {}\n".format(dead_devices))
logfile.write('Total devices that had connection errors: {}\n'.format(conn_errors_devices))
logfile.write('Total devices that had enable password errors: {}\n'.format(enable_errors_devices))
if OUTFILE:
    OUT.close()
logfile.close()
```

Also this script needs to login into 150 Routers , mybe threads for paralel connection will be good?
Can some one help me please?

Comment: Can some one help me please?